# How to fix or replace badly generated faces with good quality faces?

Tags: image-generation, text-to-image

I liked making images with bing image creator. But the face looks bad.

I wonder if there is a way I can bring the image into stable diffusion and fix the face up to make it look good.

A good answer to this question would be a detailed set of instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

A few ideias in how to solve your problem:

- You could try to generate a image based on this image, with a few tries and a little bit of luck you could get a similar image with a better face.
- You could try this online free tool that allow you to edit only a part of the image. https://imgcreator.zmo.ai/ai-generator?type=SWAP_ANYTHING
- You could try Adobe Beta Generative Fill tool to regenerate the face or the free online alternative https://clipdrop.co/uncrop.
- This tool automatic does this but for videos: https://www.deepswap.ai/pt/faceswap

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, but this isn't an answer to my question.